# Adding a for loop inside jQuery html method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, dynamic

I am trying to add for-loop inside the for-loop with some dynamic html content. but its not working properly. can anyone suggest me how to properly add dynamic html content in for-loop

i have tried removing the + sign but it is not working

```
for (i = 0; i <= NOofFeature - 1; i++) {

        var amenities = results[i].amenities.map(amenity => amenitiesUiMap[amenity]);

        featureitem += '<div class="item">'+
        '<div class="imgTitle">'+
        '<a><img src="http://192.168.1.211:3000/facility' + results[i].images[0].url + '"  height="150px" alt="" /></a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<p style="font-weight:500;font-size:16px;">' + results[i].name + '</p>'+

         for (amenityIndex in amenities) {

            featureitem += '<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;">' + amenities[amenityIndex].img + ' ' + amenities[amenityIndex].name + '</span>'+

        }
        '</div>';

    };

    $(".Featureprop").html(featureitem);
```

Will fetch all the data and print `<div class="item"> ....</div>` one by one

```
<div class="item">
<div class="imgTitle"><a><img src="http://192.168.1.211:3000/facility/image/5d1c7ae723da621f20710c2a_441292467724100.png" height="150px" alt=""></a></div>
<p style="font-weight:500;font-size:16px;">Bhagini Suites</p>
<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;"><i class="fas fa-couch"></i> Air Conditioning</span>
<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Airport Transfer</span>
<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i> Car Park</span>
<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i> Coffee Maker</span>
<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;"><i class="fas fa-dumbbell"></i> Gym</span>
<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;"><i class="fas fa-swimming-pool"></i> Private Pool</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Straightaway - did you mean `<=` or `<` in your loop?

Comment: remove the last `+` from `results[i].name + '</p>'+` and from `'</span>'+` and add `featureitem += ` to the last div

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: You're trying to insert an entire for loop into a sum of strings; how's that supposed to work? On the other hand, if you keep adding to the html string, it *should* work.

Comment: Plesae chagne `i <= NOofFeature - 1` to `i < NOofFeature` too

Comment: Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/s7eLb3w4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a string and concatenate that inside the outer one.

A few things can help you here:

- Map can iterate through your array in a single expression rather than using a block
- Template strings allow you to inline the object lookup you have to make your code more concise

Try replacing the inside for loop with:

```
amenities.map(amenity => `<span style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;">${amenity.img} ${amenity.name}</span>`).join('')
```